# Amazon EC2 からのファイルダウンロード時のデータ転送量について

Tags: http, amazon-ec2, vpc

始めてご質問させていただきます。
AWSのEC2上に建てたwebサーバからのファイルダウンロード（http）時のデータ転送料金について、自分で調べてみたのですがアウトバウンド通信料金の部分ががよくわからないのでご教示いただきたいです。

例えば、Webサーバに設置した1GBのファイルをユーザがダウンロードしたとするとサーバはユーザに対して1GBファイルを送信すると思うのですが、この時の通信料金はサーバ側からアウトバウンドで1GB分になりますでしょうか？

また、この場合ファイルが100回ダウンロードされたとすると 100 * 1GB = 100GB分のアウトバウンド通信料金を払うことになるのでしょうか？

※いたずらでダウンロードされまくると物凄い料金を請求されてしまうのではないかと考え質問させていただきました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

計算は合っていそうです。

いたずらを受けたくないのであれば、認証などアクセス制御を行う等の対策をしましょう。

Comment: やはりそうなんですね。では、パブリックに公開するWebサーバにはあまり大きなファイルは置かない方が良いですね。。。ありがとうございます！